# JSF navigation rule - default behavior

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

JSF 2.0 navigation rules allows you to define how some pages will redirect you by using the HTTP Location header. But if I haven't defined any global rules and the specified method returns an outcome that is not configured in a rule, how will the application behave?

Will it redirect me to a page named as the method return string? Will it put the method return in the HTTP response body? Or will it simply drive me back to the initial page?

**EDIT:** Trying a better explanation...

I'm conducting a source code analysis in an application that uses jsf navigation rules. I noticed that i'm able to change the EL expression that gets executed by changing a redirection request, but the method called by the redirection returns only a short string that latter gets translated to a URL based in a navigation rule.

What i'm thinking about is: what if one changes the method called by the EL expression to an existing one whose return doesn't fit the navigation rules? I'm not able to test it myself because the code is not compilable (absent classes) and i did not receive a working credential to access it. That's why i asked my fellow SO colleagues to help me in this seemingly simple question.

Comment: i am working with `jsf`, with the `outcome` and with the `rules` if i understand your question you want to know if it's possible to give the path from a `String` method ?!?

Comment: This question is strange as the answer can easily be found by just testing and observing it yourself. Aren't you essentially asking how to perform a redirect using implicit navigation? Because, by default it indeed doesn't send a redirect.

Comment: I'm not a developer, so i don't have a working test server for testing that. I'm just thought that the devs here would be able to answer that without further trouble, as it seemed (in my limited understanding) to be a theoretical question.

I searched the project but was unable to find that behavior in the documentation.

As my question proved it misleading, i'll edit it.